# When signalR connection is lost to hub proxy always stays in reconnecting state for 2 minutes

Tags: c#, websocket, signalr

I inherited a c# .net application that communicates with a SignalR Hub Proxy on a different server. On occasion the connection in the .net application to the hub proxy is lost and it will drop into a reconnecting state for exactly two minutes whenever this happens. I have tried a few different things to try and reduce this time without success. At the end of the 2 minutes it will flip back from reconnecting to connected and communications will resume.

I'd honestly like these connections to recover immediately but even being to reduce it from 2 minutes would help drastically with other issues. I find it odd that it is always exactly 2 minutes but I have not found why the hub proxy connection always takes that long to recover.

Forcefully creating the connection with WebSocketTransport made no difference to this behaviour either.

It is currently built around Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR which is supposed to auto reconnect but the websockets will remain reconnecting for the 2 minutes when it occurs. The following exception is then expected since it is reconnecting but it's not clear why it's always the 2 minute span to reconnect.

"Data cannot be sent because the WebSocket connection is reconnecting"

Also If i kill the SignalR server and restart it, it doesn't sit reconnecting for 2 minutes and it will connect to the re-launched instance right away. This happens while everything is up and running.

Comment: Have you checked your client connection configuration? You can define automatic reconnect parameters as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/javascript-client?view=aspnetcore-3.1#reconnect-clients)

Comment: @kavanka that is for the AspNetCore variant this is currently built around the AspNet version and I don't see how to change that 2 minute behaviour in this version.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
`    var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl('/WebLogHub')
    .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Debug)
    .withAutomaticReconnect()
    .build();`
```